# Forward request to same <div> once submit is pressed using Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page with two `<div>'s`, which get displayed based on the selection is made using a drop down particular selected value.

one of the div is by default displayed when a page is opened or refreshed. I needed to display some results onto second div which is not by default. Can anyone please suggest.

Below is my code so far

> Form having a drop down

```
<form id='form' method='post' action='/log/'> <input type="hidden" name="pick" value="firstDiv">

<h4>Type of Report</h4> <select id="type" name="choices" onchange="categorySelectHandler(this)">
    <option value="Top">Top Choice</option>
    <option value="Info">Information Choice</option> </select>
```

First div

```
<div id='firstDivision' style="display: block">
    <h4>By select: <span id="SelectName"> </span></h4>

    //my logic
</div>
```

Second DIV----

```
<div id='secondDivision' style="display: none">
    <form id='form2' method=post>
        <input type="hidden" name="pick" value="secondDiv">
        <h4>Enter value to get the information below:</h4>
        <select id='identity2' name="info">
            <option value="val1">choice1</option>
            <option value="val2">choice2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="dynamicText">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
            //display result logic

       </div>
```

once the dropdown chooses `Info` it changes the div and display, now when I  select things from drop down and hit submit button, I need to display my output in that div itself.

But currently, when I hit submit it redirects me to earlier default div instead and if I then select INFO option it then display that page.

Below is my servlet code:

```
if ("secondDivision".equals(pick)) {
            InformationDAOImpl ad = new InformationDAOImpl();
            PResponse pr = null;

            String selection = req.getParameter("info");
            String inputText = req.getParameter("dynamicText");

            if (selection.equals("val1")) {
                String sql = "Select name, char from table2 where text='" + inputText + "'";
                pr = ad.getProdData(sql);
            } else if (selection.equals("val2")) {
                String sql = "Select name, char from table2 where value2='" + inputText + "'";
                pr = ad.getResult(sql);
            }
            requset.setAttribute("data", pr);
            Util.forward(req, resp, this, "/log/testPage.jsp
```

");

Can anyone please guide, or suggest how can I change this line and have myself redirect to the same div.

I assume I need to make change here

> Util.forward(req, resp, this, "/log/testPage.jsp");

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With a regular HTML form submit you can't do this.  You need to use AJAX to do the submit, and then write the response into the DIV with javascript. And it has nothing to do with any request forwarding. You'll want just a servlet that returns some HTML, not to forward back to the JSP.  Take a look at the $.ajax() function in jQuery.

```
         $.ajax({
             type : "POST",
             url : "/log/",
             data : {
                 //your parameters
             },
             success : function(data)
             {
                 $("#firstDivision").html(data);
             }
         });
```